# Hadoop 2.6.0 wordcount example not running showing errors

Tags: hadoop

```
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount input output
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
15/07/10 03:03:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/07/10 03:03:16 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/07/10 03:03:17 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/rahul/.staging/job_1436477230469_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
15/07/10 03:03:17 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/rahul/.staging/job_1436477230469_0001
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/rahul/.staging/job_1436477230469_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs if you don't have any Datanodes running; if you're just running locally, just make sure the `etc/hadoop/slaves` and `etc/hadoop/master` both contain `localhost` or the hostname of your machine, and then run:

```
sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

If you're running in distributed mode, you just need to make sure your worker hostnames are populated into the `etc/hadoop/slaves` file before running `sbin/start-dfs.sh`.

You may also just want to reboot everything:

```
sbin/stop-all.sh
sbin/start-all.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Dennis. 
I would also add that in order to make sure that the datanodes are running. You can issue the command:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

it will show you the states of the datanodes.

If the datanodes still refuse to run, you can always go to the machine where you are running the datanodes and go to hadoop/logs
then open the file:
hadoop-datanode-NameOfTheMachine.log

And look for whatever error it is showing you in the end of the file.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

This error belongs to a connection issue, first check with log files if you find this type of error: http://commandstech.com/hadoop-job-yarn-staging-error-while-executing-simple-job/
Simply stop all services and restart the services.